# Irregular Symfony exception: renderBlock() must be an instance of FormView, null given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

We have a strange error in our Symfony 2 project. We use Symfony forms, and we don't have any problems in our development environment, but do receive messages of an error in production. An error we can't replicate, and never had. Everything works fine when we test (both in prod & dev) but we do receive notifications of this error happening.

We are notified of the error:

> "exception":"[object]       (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, null given

Most important code (Stripped for compactness & readability )

Formtype:

```
class WishlistType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('rank', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            // Image is deprecated and will be removed.
            ->add('image');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => Item::class,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, $url)
{
    /** @var Participant $participant */
    $participant = $this->get('participant_repository')->findOneByUrl($url);
    if ($participant === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $wishlistForm = $this->createForm(
        WishlistType::class,
        $participant,
        [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl(
                'wishlist_update',
                ['url' => $participant->getUrl()]
            ),
        ]
    );

    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return [
            'entry' => $participant,
            'wishlistForm' => $wishlistForm->createView(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
    {{ form_start(wishlistForm, {'attr': {'id': 'add_item_to_wishlist_form'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(wishlistForm._token) }}
    <table>

          <!-- ADD SOMETHING TO YOUR WISHLIST -->
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>{{ 'entry_show_valid.label.description'|trans }}</th>
              <th>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-success add-new-entry">
                      {{ 'entry_show_valid.btn.add_wishlist'|trans }}
                  </button>
              </th>
          </tr>
          </thead>

          <!-- OVERVIEW OF ITEMS IN WISHLIST, AND POSSIBILITY TO REMOVE SINGLE ITEMS-->
          <tbody>
            {% for item in wishlistForm.wishlistItems %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form_widget(item.rank) }}
                        <span>{{ item.rank.vars.value }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        {{ form_widget(item.description, {'attr': {'class': 'wishlistitem-description'} }) }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" >
                            <span>{{ 'entry_show_valid.btn.update_item'|trans }}</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button">
                            <span>{{ 'entry_show_valid.btn.remove_item'|trans }}</span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ form_end(wishlistForm, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Form handling is done over Ajax, but request is handled as regular symfony form (`$wishlistForm->handleRequest($request);` etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you can do this :

```
 {% for item in wishlistForm.wishlistItems %}
```

because I don't see any 'wishlistItems' in your form declaration.
For me, this code has to fail at this line...

Comment: Thanks for your input. The code above is a little stripped to keep it compact and readable. No essential parts are removed, and this has been removed, but this is implemented in the wishlistType. The code works for us, everything works fine, also listening all items in the wishlist. But occasionally we do receive automatic emails about this happening.